# Laravel sanctum change csrf cookie route

Tags: laravel

How could I change laravel sanctum csrf cookie route to `/api/sanctum/csrf-cookie` ?

I tried adding this to api.php routes:

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Controllers\CsrfCookieController;
Route::get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie', CsrfCookieController::class . '@show')->middleware('web');
```

But it looks for this controller under app/http/controllers where it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So if anyone wondering, there should be prefix within config file that is default set to 'sanctum' within a package service provider.

So if you want to change it to API routes you should go to `config/sanctum.php` and add `'prefix' => 'api'`.

Comment: don't forget run `php artisan config:cache` after changes

Comment: Works correctly in Laravel 11 even though the `prefix` key is not present in the default `sanctum.php` file.

Answer (score 6):

you can create a controller CsrfController and make it extends 
 (*Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Controllers\CsrfCookieController*)

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Controllers\CsrfCookieController
class CsrfController extends CsrfCookieController {}
```

and then you can link your route

```
Route::get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'CsrfController@show')->middleware('web');
```

Answer (score 6):

another flexible solution is to set

```
'routes' => false
```

in **config/sanctum.php** ,then define a new route in **routes\api.php**

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Controllers\CsrfCookieController;

Route::get('/csrf', [CsrfCookieController::class, 'get'])->name('csrf');
```

like so, you can choose the proper route to suit your needs

Comment: That´s a quite flexible way to solve this issue. However, when I add that route no cookies are sent to the browser (204 is returned as expeted). If I use the "original" sanctum route, the csrf cookie is sent back. Besides: 'get' doesn´t exist on the CsrfCookieController anymore - i think its now 'show'.

Comment: Here´s the way it works: Route::get('/csrf-cookie',CsrfCookieController::class . '@show')->middleware('web')->name('sanctum.csrf-cookie');